# Why is Vivaldi crooked on LinuxMint 20 XFCE over Remmina VNC?

Tags: linux-mint, vnc, opennebula, vivaldi

I have installed a virtual machine with Linux Mint 20 XFCE. I access it with Remmina VNC client over Opennebula's built-in VNC server. Everything if fine, except Vivaldi browser is crooked. (See attached screenshot). It does not behave like that all the time, just sporadically. All other programs behave. Any idea why?[image]